# Insert into two tables in one statement SQL Server

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, winforms

I am unsure of how to go about this problem.

I have three tables, `bookcollection`, `books` and `users`.

```
bookcollection : bookc_id, bookc_bookid, bookc_bookuser
books : bookid, title, author, year
users : userid, username, password
```

- `bookid` is the foreign key to `bookc_bookid`
- `userid` is the foreign key to `bookc_bookuser`

I have a C# Winforms application and I am trying to insert a new book with textboxes. However, I've hit a wall. I am able to insert a new book into the `books` table. But, I also need to be able to insert the `userid` and the `bookid` into the `bookcollection` table so it would be in the user's book collection.

This is what I have.

```
private void add()
{
    using (SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(constr))
    {
        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("INSERT INTO books (title, author, year) VALUES (@t, @a, @y)");
        cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
        cmd.Connection = connection;
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@t", title.Text);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@a", author.Text);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@y", year.Text);
        connection.Open();
        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
    }
```

On the main form I have a string which is passed with username like `public string Username;`

Can anyone help me out with this? Would I need to create a stored procedure, if so how would I do this? Thanks in advance.

Comment: when you are creating parameters in regards to `Sql Server` why not use meaningful parameter names..? also here is a link to a Sql Tutorial
[Sql Basics Tutorial](http://beginner-sql-tutorial.com/sql.htm)

Answer (score 0):

Try using insert trigger on books. With trigger, when you insert a data on books, it will automatically add data to other table with given parameters.

Comment: By any chance could you give me an example or a start please?

Comment: You are using this code for one userid which user name passes on Username string value, is it right?

Comment: Well so far this code that I have just add the books into the general books table, but I need it to then insert the userid and the booksid into the bookcollection. In my main I got the userid of the logged in username with this `INNER JOIN users r ON c.bookC_userid = r.userid WHERE username LIKE '" + Username` so I get the userid from the string `Username` yes.

Comment: I guess the second query wouldn't be an INSERT though because you can't have WHERE in an INSERT clause so it would probable be an update. Update the bookcollection with userid and bookid

Comment: @1234566543 what do you mean you can't have a `WHERE` in an Insert..?? [W3cSchools Sql Tutorial & Examples](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_insert_into_select.asp)

Answer (score 0):

Then a stored procedure will be better solution to pass the parameters to data layer. try this:

```
create proc sp_AddToBookCollection
(
@bookid int,
@userid int
)
as
begin
insert into bookcollection(bookc_bookid, bookc_bookuser)
values (@bookid,@userid)
end
```

while using this procedure, you should pass the userid value to the query.

Comment: Hey thanks for that, however I actually think that a trigger would be more sufficient in this situation so it would update the the bookcollection instead that way i could pass the Username string in there somehow? Is this possible? Could you help out please.

Comment: @1234566543 if you feel that a Trigger may best suit your needs.. then do a google search on how to create a trigger.. please show a litte bit more effort on your part..

Comment: Triggers work on a table on data layer, in your case, you want to add data to bookcollection table automatically, which takes bookid and userid parameters. when you add data to books table, data layer gets bookid from inserted data but userid is missing. you should pass this value from application layer. thus, you should use stored procedure.